# Why does numpy.random.Generator.choice provides different results (seeded) with given uniform distribution compared to default uniform distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, random, uniform-distribution, numpy-random

Simple test code:

```
pop = numpy.arange(20)
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(1)
rng.choice(pop,p=numpy.repeat(1/len(pop),len(pop))) # yields 10
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(1)
rng.choice(pop) # yields 9
```

The [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.choice.html) says:

> The probabilities associated with each entry in a. If not given the sample assumes a uniform distribution over all entries in a.

I don't know of any other way to create a uniform distribution, but `numpy.repeat(1/len(pop),len(pop))`.

Is numpy using something else? Why?

If not, how does setting the distribution affects the seed?

Shouldn't the distribution and the seed be independent?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution doesn't affect the seed. Details as bellow:

I checked out the source code:  [numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L669](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f1c4ba3e97cbf5c494f29531b35da6144cac5aec/numpy/random/_generator.pyx#L669)

If `p` is given, it will use `rng.random` to get a random value:

```
import numpy

pop = numpy.arange(20)
seed = 1
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(seed)

# rng.choice works like bellow
rand = rng.random()
p = numpy.repeat(1/len(pop),len(pop))
cdf = p.cumsum()
cdf /= cdf[-1]
uniform_samples = rand
idx = cdf.searchsorted(uniform_samples, side='right')
idx = numpy.array(idx, copy=False, dtype=numpy.int64) # yields 10
print(idx)

# -----------------------
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(seed)
idx = rng.choice(pop,p=numpy.repeat(1/len(pop),len(pop))) # same as above
print(idx)
```

If `p` is not given, it will use `rng.integers` to get a random value:

```
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(seed)
idx = rng.integers(0, pop.shape[0]) # yields 9
print(idx)
# -----------------------
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(seed)
idx = rng.choice(pop) # same as above
print(idx)
```

You can play around using different `seed` value. I don't know what happens in `rng.random` and `rng.integers`, but you could see that they behave differently. That's why you got different results.

Answer (score 0):

A more idiomatic way of creating a uniform distribution with numpy would be:

```
numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=None)
```

or in your case
numpy.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=20.0, size=1)

Alternatively, you could simply do

```
rng = numpy.random.default_rng(1)
rng.uniform()*20
```

As for your question on why the two methods of calling the rnd.choice result in different outputs, my guess would be that they are executed slightly differently by the interpreter and thus, although you start at the same random initialization, by the time the random variable call is executed, you are at a different random elements in the two calls and get different results.

Comment: looking at the docs, it seems like numpy.random.uniform doesn't create a uniform distribution, but it samples from a continuous uniform distribution. On my computer, it just yields a float between low and high, as the documentation prescribes.

Comment: if your guess is correct, it would be a bug in numpy. Sure, a low impact, but hard to fix bug, but nevertheless a bug.